# why precision is not good when I use a generator?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

Good morning!

i trained my model using the generator, the result was not good, but when i change it to model.fit the result is good.
what is is the difference between them in term of result?

thanks.

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: the question is not clear??

Comment: It is not appropriate for this site. There are other sites on the stack exchange network that deal with methodological issues